# Store MongoDB object in Redis cache problem

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework2

I am having hard time storing some `MongoDb` objects to `Redis cache`.

I am fetching the items from the database like this:

```
$cursor = $this->manager->executeQuery($this->collection, $query);
```

Which returns `object` of class `MongoDB\BSON\Cursor`.

Since I cannot store this in the Redis cache, I am trying to convert it to an array to do so.

I tried the following things:

```
$redis_cursor = \MongoDB\BSON\toJSON(\MongoDB\BSON\fromPHP($cursor->toArray()));
```

which produces the following error: `Serialization of 'MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID' is not allowed`

I also tried this:

```
$redis_cursor = \MongoDB\BSON\toJSON(\MongoDB\BSON\fromPHP($cursor->toArray()));
```

which produces this: `Cursors cannot yield multiple iterators`

Another try was this:

```
$redis_cursor = \MongoDB\BSON\toJSON(\MongoDB\BSON\fromPHP($cursor));
```

Which returns an `empty string`

Whatever I try, I pretty much get one of the two errors mentioned above.
Any help would be appreciated!

I am using `mongodb version 1.1.5` if that is of any importance.